# Implement the paypal recurring payment using C# sdk

Tags: c#, paypal

I am implementing the recurring payment in my site using the paypal C# sdk.Is it possible to start billing the user only after a fixed time say one month or 2months once the users enters his credit card information instead of making the payment right away and then continue payment successively on later date.I basically should be able start payment after certain period once user signs up using premium membership plan and then continue successive payment.

Also i am not supposed to implement the trail feature.But i would like to now what happens if the users do not upgrade if the trial period expires.How does paypal respond to it and what can i do from application to bring user back to normal user if trial period expires.

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if paypal support this what you can do is look for direct Debit payment you can look for api like saferpay. Otherwise you will have to generate a transaction every month at a given date(and this may look fraudulent)

Regards